# R - Data.table aggregation - which type of join is needed?

Tags: r, datatable

Once again, I have a simple problem that is driving me nuts.

Data.table structure looks like following. I have a two data.table that are similar to each other but have the identical structure. It needs to be **"merged"** to the first table but also retain rows with non-matching rows/values in the second table. `N_Events` is a counter variable of events grouped by `Date`. Each table stores the counter variable.

**The challenge:** Both tables do not store the same dates.

```
Date_1       N_Events_1
1990-01-01   1 
1992-02-01   3
1992-02-01   3
1992-02-01   3
1997-04-01   2
1997-04-01   2

Date_2       N_Events_2
1990-01-01   1 
1992-02-01   4
1992-02-01   4
1992-02-01   4
1992-02-01   4
1999-04-01   1
```

I would love to extract the **N_events for each unique Date** to get the table below and then join them. I would love to store the intermediate results in a dt as well.

```
# Intermediate aggregation results stored in dt_summ_1
Date_1       N_Events_1
1990-01-01   1 
1992-02-01   3
1997-04-01   2

# Intermediate aggregation results stored in dt_summ_2
Date_2       N_Events_2
1990-01-01   1 
1992-02-01   4
1999-04-01   1

Date         N_Events_1   N_Events_2
1990-01-01   1            1
1992-02-01   3            4
1997-04-01   2            NA
1999-04-01   NA           1   
# NAs could also be stored as zero as I subsequently convert 
# the NAs to zero to allow plotting the time series of N_Events 1 & 2
```

What I have tried so far:

```
setkey(dt, Date)
dt_1[, N_Events, by = Date] # not giving me unique dates
dt_1[, .(unique(Date), N_Events)] # warning about item 1 (being date) being recycled with remainder

merge(dt_1, dt_2, by.x = "Date_1", by.y = "Date_2, all = TRUE) 
# Errors in 185736 rows; more than 37510 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). 
# Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the 
# same group in x over and over again.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, I think you should look for `full_join()` function of the dplyr package. You will join them together on the date column. It will give NA's in the respective Event 1 or 2 column if there is a date missing in one df.

Comment: That did not work for me unfortunately. Somehow is bothered by the date format ....

Comment: So what is the error message exactly? What is the class of the Date column?